# Dynamic jasper: How to add a vertical line using dynamic jasper API

Tags: dynamic-jasper

How to add a vertical line using dynamic jasper API.

I need to show a vertical line as a column separator how to do this using dynamic jasper API?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the right or left border between two column elements and mimicking a vertical line.
The line will grow as more records are added.

If the font size is to small to do this. Just resize the textfield elements and set a padding.
You wont notice the larger text fields if you use the right padding